# Echo output from a custom task

Tags: apache, ant

I have a black-box ant task which creates output that I consume in another task. I need to write the output of `create-UUIDs` into a file. Neither of my ideas are working, because the redirector and echo tasks do not accept adhoc tasks as input.

Here is my code:

```
<redirector output="atest.txt">
    <createUUIDs numberOfUUIDsToPrint="1"/>
</redirector>
```

Also tried

```
<echo file="atest.txt">
    <createUUIDs numberOfUUIDsToPrint="1"/>
</echo>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using [recorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845137/capture-ant-output):

```
<record name="atest.txt" action="start" emacsmode="true"/>
    <createUUIDs numberOfUUIDsToPrint="1"/>
<record name="atest.txt" action="stop"/>
```